# Hyperledger Sawtooth installation error

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

Can anyone please help me to get out of this error??
 i am stuck there and cannot find a solution to it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWy0A.png)

Answer (score 3):

Your port 8080 is in use. Either kill it or change the port while running up docker.
command to Kill a process on port 8080 in ubuntu
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:8080`

Answer (score 0):

To find processes, type `sudo lsof -t -i:8080`
Kill them.
If the error occurs again, check if something is restarting these processes.
Perhaps they are in Docker containers and have been restarted or recreated.